# detect-custom-labels missing from AWS CLI (Windows)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-rekognition

I am following instructions both here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rekognition/detect-custom-labels.html and on the AWS Console itself in order to test recognition against a model / dataset I have built using custom labels. The console advises on using the aws CLI to make requests against your model, however when I try the suggested commands, specifically

```
PS C:\Users\james> aws rekognition start-project-version
```

And

```
PS C:\Users\james> aws rekognition detect-custom-labels
```

I get the error:

```
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
aws.exe: error: argument operation: Invalid choice, valid choices are:

compare-faces                            | create-collection
create-stream-processor                  | delete-collection
delete-faces                             | delete-stream-processor
describe-stream-processor                | detect-faces
detect-labels                            | detect-moderation-labels
detect-text                              | get-celebrity-info
get-celebrity-recognition                | get-content-moderation
get-face-detection                       | get-face-search
get-label-detection                      | get-person-tracking
index-faces                              | list-collections
list-faces                               | list-stream-processors
recognize-celebrities                    | search-faces
search-faces-by-image                    | start-celebrity-recognition
start-content-moderation                 | start-face-detection
start-face-search                        | start-label-detection
start-person-tracking                    | start-stream-processor
stop-stream-processor                    | help
```

My first thought was that my CLI was out of date. I updated it, and the version is now:

```
PS C:\Users\james> aws --version
aws-cli/1.14.53 Python/2.7.9 Windows/8 botocore/1.9.6
PS C:\Users\james>
```

Yet still these commands for rekognition custom labels / projects do not appear. Where am I going wrong here? :/

EDIT: Updated CLI, which lets me run the commend, but now I get this error:

Command:

```
aws rekognition detect-custom-labels --project-version-arn "arn:aws:rekognition:us-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:project/api-dev-rtest/version/api-dev-rtest.2019-12-07T16.35.53/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" --image "{"S3Object": {"Bucket": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx","Name": "James/yes.JPG"}}" --endpoint-url https://rekognition.us-west-2.amazonaws.com --region us-west-2
```

Error:

```
Unknown options: S3Object: {Bucket: xxxxxxxxxxxxx,Name: James/yes.JPG}}
```

Comment: 1.14.53 is really old version and it is not supporting the custom-label commands for the recognition.

Comment: I thought i'd updated the cli, but it hadn't worked. Updated now, which is great, however have hit another issue - I am posting it in my original question

Answer (score 1):

Try to put --image parameter into single quotes:

```
... --image '{"S3Object": {"Bucket": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx","Name": "James/yes.JPG"}}'

aws rekognition detect-custom-labels --project-version-arn "arn:aws:rekognition:us-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:project/api-dev-rtest/version/api-dev-rtest.2019-12-07T16.35.53/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" --image '{"S3Object": {"Bucket": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx","Name": "James/yes.JPG"}}' --region us-west-2
```

Comment: Tried that, didn't work :( Error parsing parameter '--image': Invalid JSON: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
JSON received: {S3Object: {Bucket: api-dev-dpstorage-s3,Name: James/yes.JPG}}

Comment: In linux I can use `--image "{\"S3Object\": {\"Bucket\": \"bucket\",\"Name\": \"path/file.jpg\"}}"`. In Windows I'd try `--image "{^"S3Object^": {^"Bucket^": ^"bucket^",^"Name^": ^"path/file.jpg^"}}"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your boto3 version to 1.10.34,
try to use command $sudo pip install --upgrade boto3